# Windows 7 Ionic Framework: zipalign 4 -v myapp-release-unsigned.apk myapp.apk won't work

Tags: ionic-framework, zipalign

When i run command above, nothing happens. It doesn't create "myapp.apk". I found nothing online to guide me. Does someone know what is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
$ zipalign -v 4 HelloWorld-release-unsigned.apk HelloWorld.apk
```

instead

```
$ zipalign 4 -v HelloWorld-release-unsigned.apk HelloWorld.apk
```